# return scope_identity() question

Tags: sql-server

environment sql server 2005

In my stored proc i am calling another stored proc to insert several rows into several tables. The last row inserted i want to pass the identity of that row to the original stored proc. I am doing this by using `return scope_identity();` My understanding is `return` is only used for error messages/status codes. Is this a "good" way of doing what I need to do, or is there another "better" way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All procedures have an integer return value.  Your method would work, there is no hard and fast rule against it.

Alternatively, you could return an output parameter.

Example:

```
create procedure YourProcedure
  @ID output
as
  insert into YourTable (bunch of values)
  select @ID = scope_identity()
go
```

You then call your procedure as follows:

```
declare @TheID int
exec YourProcedure @TheID output
select @TheID
```

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways:

- OUTPUT parameter (as per datagod's answer)
- RETURN (as you noted)
- A simple SELECT which can be consumed say with ExecuteScalar

I'd usually use an OUTPUT parameter because it's the lightest way.

Note: If you are inserting several rows into one table and only getting the last IDENTITY there is no guarantee that the previous rows are contiguous